# Simple but elusive Integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

this is a self-made problem:

$$\bar{z} = \int_{0}^{1} y(s)ds$$
$$z = \int_{0}^{1} s y(s)ds$$

And I want to evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{1} s^2 y(s)ds$$

in terms of $\bar{z}$ and $z$.

This was my first attempt but it has an error in it so I am hoping for new ideas:

---

My approach is to use integration by parts but I'm not sure if it works:
$$u = s^2$$
$$dv = y(s)ds$$

So

$$\int_{0}^{1} s^2 y(s)ds = s^{2} Y(s) |_{0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1} 2s y(s)ds$$

Where $Y(s)$ is the antiderivative of $y(s)$.

Is it true that $$s^{2} Y(s) |_{0}^{1} = \int_{0}^{1} y(s)$$ ?

Or do I just take $$Y(s) = \int_{c}^{1} y(s)$$ for some constant $c$ so that $$s^{2} Y(s) |_{0}^{1} = \int_{c}^{1} y(s)$$? In this case I don't know what should determine $c$.

Thanks for your thoughts and attention!

Comment: The integration by parts is still not correct, the integrand should be $2sY(s)$. To answer your question, it's not but we do have $$s^2Y(s)\Bigr|_0^1 = \int_0^1y(s)ds - Y(0)$$

Comment: Thank you @NinadMunshi! I appreciate you catching that, though it means my goal of defining $\int_{0}^{1} s^{2} y(s) ds$ in terms of $\bar{z}$ and $z$ is even further than I thought. Any ideas?

Comment: It is great that you included an attempt. Please do note remove it, even if it is incorrect, as it provides useful context and background to your post.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff OK! I rolled back my edit so it's back in the original form.

Answer (score 0):

$s^2Y(s)|_0^1 = (s|_1)^2 Y(1) - (s|_0)^2 Y(0) = Y(1)$

but $\int_0^1 y(s)ds = Y(1) - Y(0)$

You do have freedom to choose a constant term in $Y(s)$ such that $Y(0)=0$.  So you can set the two expressions to be the same.  But they are not necessarily so.

Comment: Thank you, you did respond to something I focused on in the original post of my question but @Ninad Munshi pointed out that the other term in my integration by parts was incorrect so now we are back to square one finding a useful way to find $\int_{0}^{1} s^2 y(s) ds$ in terms of $\bar{z}$ and $z$. Do you have any thoughts?